# Issues with tkinter widgets in the Python turtle graphics window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget, turtle-graphics

I have created a program in Python turtle graphics and have created some widgets to put in the window. However, there is one major issue with the widgets: **they just stay stuck at the bottom of the window, and I CANNOT move them ANYWHERE ELSE around the screen**. They just stay stuck at the bottom window in a line from left to right, and this becomes a real issue when having many widgets. For clarification, here is an image of what I am talking about:[image: Widgets issue]

What I want is to be able to move the widgets to the top, left, or right side of the window instead of them just being stuck to the bottom of it. And, as you can see, since I have created A LOT of widgets, the fact that I cannot do this becomes a real issue. **So, why is this happening and how would I fix it?** Also, just in case, below is the a code block for **one** of my menus and **one** of my buttons:

Menu code block:

```
tb = Menubutton(text = "Change pen thickness")
tb.pack(side = 'left')
tb.menu = Menu(tb, tearoff = 0)
tb["menu"] = tb.menu
thick = tb.menu
thick.add_command(label = "1", command = width1)
thick.add_command(label = "2", command = width2)
thick.add_command(label = "3", command = width3)
thick.add_command(label = "4", command = width4)
thick.add_command(label = "5", command = width5)
thick.add_command(label = "6", command = width6)
thick.add_command(label = "7", command = width7)
thick.add_command(label = "8", command = width8)
thick.add_command(label = "9", command = width9)
thick.add_command(label = "10", command = width10)
tb.pack()
```

Button code block:

```
change = Button(text = "Change letter dimensions", command = NewLetterDimensions)
change.pack(side = 'left')
```

The fact that the widgets are packed to the left is not the issue, as even before I did that, the widgets would stay stuck to the bottom of the window. The only difference was that they were stacked from top to bottom instead of left to right.

Google has not been much help in finding a solution, so I am turning over to SO. Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT:** I have tried adding `master = getcanvas()` and made that the master of one of the widgets like so:

```
master = getcanvas()
mb = Menubutton(master, text = "Change color")
```

And now when I run the program, it just hangs and eventually crashes every single time. I had tried this before when I had only one widget, and it still yielded the same results. I don't really know what else to do, so help is very much appreciated.

**EDIT # 2:** I have also tried to create a tkinter frame that I pack to the bottom of the canvas and then make that frame the master of the menu, like so:

```
master = Frame()
master.pack(side = 'top')
mb = Menubutton(master, text = "Change color")
mb.pack(side = 'top')
```

However, even though both are set to `side = 'top'`, it still stays at the bottom of the screen, with just the widget on top of the others, like so:

[image: New method failure]

What is still going wrong?

**EDIT # 3:** This is what I am now getting as per the answers advice:

[image: What I have now]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the order you are calling the geometry manager `pack`

`pack` will add the widget to the **available** space on the master widget/frame/window, and stick it to the specified edge (default is `top`). So in your case you are calling `pack` on the canvas first, which will stick it to the top of your window, and then whatever you add, will be added under it, because it is sticked to the top edge, and your available space is under.

You have several options to do what you want to do, you can change the order of declaration of your widgets, declaring first what's going to be on top, or left, and pack it as such. Which is not very pretty. Or you can declare all your widgets and leave all the `pack` commands at the end, and then calling them in the order you need them, which is better but still not the best option.

I would suggest create different frames for each group of elements, for example a frame of menus, a frame of buttons and a frame for the canvas, manage the internal geometry of the elements in each frame, and then manage the geometry of the frames in the window.

Or you can use `grid` instead of `pack` to manage the geometry. Mind you it is not recommended to mix the use of both, it can get messy.

Comment: How would I create a frame for the canvas? I called `getcanvas()` and then did this `mem = getcanvas();
    widgetmaster = Frame(mem);
    widgetmaster.pack(side = 'top')` However, now whenever I start the program, it gets stuck and I have to kill it.

Comment: Create the frame before creating the canvas, `FrameCanvas = Frame()` then when creating the canvas, create it IN the frame `YourCanvas = Canvas( FrameCanvas, other_arguments)`. Now `YourCanvas.pack(side='your choice')` will determine the position of the canvas IN the frame, and `FrameCanvas.pack(side='your choice')` will determine the position of the frame in the window

Comment: Okay, so I have created the canvas. But I am using an undefined instance of the canvas, so how would I redefine the canvas as `YourCanvas` without creating a `RawTurtle`?

Comment: What do you mean by "undefined instance of the canvas"?, as long as you create the canvas in the frame, you can just focus on the geometry of the frame, it will move the canvas accordingly.

Comment: But the turtle draws somewhere else, as in not in the defined canvas. What I meant to say is, how would I make the canvas the master for the `turtle` to draw on? Look at EDIT # 3 for more information.

Comment: The first argument for the `turtle` class is the canvas in which it will draw `YourTurtle = turtle.RawTurtle(YourCanvas)`

Comment: Is there any way for me to not have to define a turtle, but still change the canvas? Because I have created the whole program with an undefined instance of the turtle, and I don't want to have to go through the entire program and put `t.` in front of everything when `t = RawTurtle(...)`

Comment: Shall we move this conversation to the chat?, I guess it's going to be easier to understand each other

Comment: Okay, let me move it to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100343/discussion-between-r-kap-and-noel-segura).

Comment: @R.Kap, I found a super broken solution for your problem, you can make your own `turtle` module and add the command `setcanvas(YourCanvas)` but it will have some weird behaviors. I would only use it as a last resort. First find the `turtle.py` document on your computer, then copy, paste and rename it in the directory of your program, name it `turtle2`, then open it, in line 120 add `setcanvas` to the list of functions and in line 1275 add the function `def setcanvas(self,cv):    self.cv=cv`. And in your program change the import and add the command `setcanvas(YourCanvas)`

Comment: Mind you, this is a super broken solution, the turtle window will appear, but the movement will be in your canvas, but if you close the turtle window, it will reopen and restart normal behaviour, so use it only as last resort